# Understanding the importance of [0] in the following Python pandas code

Tags: python, pandas

```
dataframe.mode()['Column'][0]
```

I need to know what purpose does `[0]` serve. Working on Python in Jupyter.

Comment: It’s improper formatting for one, should be `loc` or `iloc`, but it returns the first row/element in the column. Have you tried it yourself to experiment?

Answer (score 0):

`[0]` selects the first element of the Column array. (Since counting starts at 0 in python)

`['Column'][4]` would select the 5th element of the array (if it exists).

I would suggest looking into Python basics and [Python arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) a bit more before start using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

In python the first element is the 0 not the 1, so with
`dataframe.mode()['Column'][0]` you will get the first value